# Could not find class 'org.gwtwidgets.client.temp.TMouseListenerCollection'

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc

I have next parent-class:

```
public class ListUIModel<T extends BaseModel> extends BaseModel implements List<T> {

    protected ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

    public ListUIModel() {
    }

    public ListUIModel(T... models) {
        list = ArraysUtil.asList(models);
    }

    //implementation of List interface...
```

And have class derived from ListUIModel:

```
public class ProducersUIModel extends ListUIModel<ProducerUIModel> {

public ProducersUIModel() {
}

public ProducersUIModel(ProducerUIModel... producers) { 
    super(producers);
}

other methods...
```

Service method returns PublicationUIModel.

This code is compiled by gwt, and when I run the tomcat, I see this warning:

```
29 Nov 2012 09:10:59,498: ERROR http-8443-Processor21 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/] - userProfileController: ERROR: Could not find class 'org.gwtwidgets.client.temp.TMouseListenerCollection' listed in the serialization policy file '/5C1ACC115899B7BFEC8646E55EC693E0.gwt.rpc'; your server's classpath may be misconfigured
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gwtwidgets.client.temp.TMouseListenerCollection
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1377)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1223)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)...
```

And GWT's util CompileReport says:

```
org.gwtwidgets.client.temp.TMouseListenerCollection
   Serialization status
      Instantiable
   Path
      'org.gwtwidgets.client.temp.TMouseListenerCollection' is reachable as a subtype of type 'class java.util.ArrayList<T>'
      'java.util.ArrayList<T>' is reachable from field 'list' of type 'com.xalmiento.desknet.ui.client.model.ListUIModel<T>'
      'com.xalmiento.desknet.ui.client.model.ListUIModel<com.xalmiento.desknet.ui.client.model.ProducerUIModel>' is reachable as a supertype of type 'class com.xalmiento.desknet.ui.client.model.ProducersUIModel'
      'com.xalmiento.desknet.ui.client.model.ProducersUIModel' is reachable as a subtype of type 'class com.xalmiento.desknet.ui.client.model.ProducersUIModel'
```

Why GWT tries to load TMouseListenerCollection? I use ArrayList(without  in other places) and all right. It's till difficult to understand for me :(

I know that I can explicity exclude this class from .gwt.rpc policy file. But how I resolve this issue with another approach?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any chance your question got truncated? Is it "I have test class" or something else. Also provide your service class method that is using the Test class.

Comment: Sachin Shekhar R, sorry, I tried to change my issue.

Comment: No need of apology :) Can you also update your GWT version. I am guessing your are using GXT 2 with GWT 2.0 series. Also post code snippet for TMouseListenerCollection which you had earlier....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT compiler tries to list out all subtypes from ArrayList which are implementing IsSerializable. The solution is to try removing IsSerializable interface from  TMouseListenerCollection or declare list in ListUIModel as transient ( non-serializable ) if it is not to be sent over the rpc.

Comment: No, we don't use GXT, but your solution work.

I think, that when i declare "protected ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>()", then GWT shouldn't insert TMouseListenerCollection in policy file because it doesn't extend my BaseModel.

Maybe it's bug in GWT 2.3 ? How do you thinks?

Comment: It includes it because its subtype of ArrayList and IsSerializable. This is declared behaviour of GWT RPC as far I have understood and makes sense.

Comment: When I write ...ArrayList<MyClass>...(specify parameter type)  GWT doesn't add TMouseListenerCollection in policy file. But when I specified that my ArrayList have any paramter - extended only from BaseModel (<T extends BaseModel>), GWT insert this class in policy file, althoudgh I specified <T axtends BaseModel>. And all this isn't bug, right?

Comment: I think that GWT must include not all classes, but only those which inherit BaseModel. And in my case, when I write ArrayList<T axtends BaseModel>, GWT include all classes including TMouseListenerCollection. I thinks it's bug.

Comment: Okay. Can you zip up a sample minimal code and share it. I do see you have raised the issue on GWT without a sample code @ http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7826

Comment: Eventually I found existing issue on GWT : http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4438